# Matrix trace minimization of quadratic and linear terms under orthogonal manifold constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, smooth-manifolds, manifolds, nonlinear-optimization

How would one solve the following orthogonal manifold problem?

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \mbox{tr}(X^\top A X - X^\top B)\\ \text{subject to} & X^\top X = I\end{array}$$

where $A \succeq 0$. I've seen one method that successively performs the sequence of updates to reach a fixed point using closed form updates:

$$X^{(k+1)} \leftarrow \max_X \mbox{tr}(X^\top (A X^{(k)} - B)) = U V^\top$$

where $A X^{(k)} - B = U \Sigma V^\top$ (is the SVD).

I'm not entirely satisfied with this method because it is not efficient in practice. Moreover, we know that $\max_X \text{tr}(X^\top A X)$ and $\max_X \text{tr}(-X^\top B)$ separately have closed-form solutions. It, however, is not obvious to me how to combine them.

Comment: So, is $X$ square?

Comment: In general, no. But if you have any leads on the square case, I'll be happy to work with those constraints.

Comment: So, why call it "orthogonal manifold" rather than [Stiefel manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel_manifold)?

Comment: Note that if $X$ is square $$\mbox{tr} (X^\top A \, X) = \mbox{tr} ( \, A X X^\top) =  \mbox{tr} (A)$$ You have a generalization of [Orthogonal Procrustes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem).

Comment: As you have pointed out, if $X$ is square, the problem is greatly simplified (has a closed form solution).
Secondly, you're right about the Stiefel manifold comment. It is exactly right.

Comment: I was hoping someone was able to demonstrate some sort of closed form type of method rather than methods that involve iterative tangent proximal/projection steps or with Caley transforms.

Comment: Take a look at the links in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2500881/339790).

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2509243/339790), too.

Comment: Try MANOPT using Stiefel manifold  https://www.manopt.org/tutorial.html#manifolds .

Comment: Thank you Rodrigo and Mark for your generous tips!